# How to plot using a text data column from an Excel file as x axis?

Tags: excel, matlab, text, plot

I have imported in Matlab an Excel file that contains two columns, one with numeric values, and the other one with text values. The first 5 rows can be seen below:

ABF-E      0.34

HJK-D      -0.54

GHKL-I      1.34

FPLO-5      2.3

KKJLL-T     0.98

I need to plot the numeric column on the Y axis and the text column on the X axis. I can easily work with the numeric column using `xlsread` and `plot` , but I cannot manage plotting the text column. How could I do it?.

I have written the following code, but I don't know what to do for the x Axis:

```
filename = 'MyData.xlsx';

Sheet = 2

xlRange = 'B1:B60';

Yaxis = xlsread (filename,Sheet,xlRange);

Xaxis = ????????;

plot(xAxis,Yaxis)
```

I would be very grateful if somebody could help me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the [`xticklabel` property](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/axes_props.html) of the axis with your `xAxis` text. You can go along these lines:

```
[~,xAxis] = xlsread(filename,Sheet,'A1:A60'); %// read in text data. Use second output 
yAxis = xlsread(filename,Sheet,'B1:B60'); %// read in numeric data
plot(yAxis) %// This uses 1, 2, 3... as x axis values
set(gca,'xtick',1:numel(xAxis)) %// set ticks
set(gca,'xticklabel',xAxis)  %// set ticklabels with your xAxis
xlim([0 numel(xAxis)+1]) %// adjust x axis span
```

In your example, this yields:

[image]

If you want to skip some labels on the x axis to make it less cluttered: define the desired `tickStep` and then use it when setting the ticks and the ticklabels (in the two `set` lines):

```
tickStep = 6; 
[~,xAxis] = xlsread(filename,Sheet,'A1:A60'); %// read in text data. Use second output 
yAxis = xlsread(filename,Sheet,'B1:B60'); %// read in numeric data
plot(yAxis) %// This uses 1, 2, 3... as x axis values
set(gca,'xtick',1:tickStep:numel(xAxis)) %// set ticks
set(gca,'xticklabel',xAxis(1:tickStep:numel(xAxis)))  %// set ticklabels with your xAxis
xlim([0 numel(xAxis)+1]) %// adjust x axis span
```

Comment: Hello Luis, thank you very much for answering, I am going to try it and as soon as I do it I get back to you.

Comment: @Sarah Note that, if you have 60 values to plot, the names in the x axis may get too compressed. You might want to skip some values in that case

Comment: Yes, you are right, it would look very clustered, but I can't reduce the number of values as it would reduce the accuracy of the graph. Is there any way to skip labels instead of values?, I mean, for example, plotting a label every 6 values and within a vertical position so that they occupy less space?. I have been reading that it is possible using Xticklabel_rotate, but I will have to do a for loop to plot a label every 6 values?. My Matlab knowledge is quite low at the moment.

Comment: @Sarah You can skip some labels without reducing the number of values; see at the end of updated answer (no `for` loop required). As for the vertical position, I really don't know, I've never done that

Comment: Hello Luis, I have tried your code and it works perfectly fine. I'm still working on the label rotation into a vertical position, once I find out the way, I will post the code here. There is something that is confusing me a little. Where in your code are you asking to plot the values of the y-axis?, in the plot(yAxis) command?, but that's for plotting the x-axis using numeric values?, I'm confused:-(.

Comment: @Sarah `plot(yAxis)` is shorthand for `plot(1:length(yAxis), yAxis)`. So it plots the `yAxis` values on y axis versus 1,2,3,... on the x axis

Comment: Hello Luis, apparently, rotating the X-axis labels is not straightforward at all. There is not any command in Matlab that allows doing that. The only thing that I have found is a function done by somebody else: http://www.mathworks.co.uk/matlabcentral/fileexchange/3150-xticklabelrotate90. I still need to figure out how to include that function in my code or how to call to that function from my script.

Comment: I have found the way to rotate the x-axis labels:-)

Comment: @Sarah Great! How is it? Some File Exchange function?

Comment: Yes, it's a file exchange function. You can download it from the link that I have pasted before. It works with both, numeric and text x-axis labels. It took me some time as not all the functions that I found rotated text data, but this function worked for my case.

Answer (score 1):

Here, I post the code that answers all my questions from this post. I have pasted the code for the first 5 Excel rows of my graph. The function that I have used to rotate the x-Axis labels can be downloaded here: http://www.mathworks.co.uk/matlabcentral/fileexchange/3486-xticklabelrotate  [image]

```
filename='MyData.xlsx'; %// Name of the file
tickStep=1; %// Sets the tick steps
Sheet=2; %// Excel sheet number
[~,xAxis]=xlsread(filename,Sheet,'A1:A5'); %//Reads text data from Excel file. Uses   second output
yAxis=xlsread(filename,Sheet,'B1:B5'); %// Reads numeric data from Excel file.
plot(1:numel(xAxis),yAxis) %// Plots x and y-Axis in numeric format
set(gca,'xtick',1:tickStep:numel(xAxis)) %// Sets the ticks of the x-Axis
set(gca,'xticklabel',xAxis(1:tickStep:numel(xAxis))); %// Plots the text data previously read from the Excel file as x-Axis labels
xlim([0 numel(xAxis)+1]) %//Adjusts x-Axis span
xticklabel_rotate([],90,[],'Fontsize',10) %// Calls and executes the function that rotates the x-Axis labels into a vertical position with a font size of 10
```

Comment: +1 for sharing the solution after having figured everything out. -- Sidenote, it looks like an expansion of the answer by @Luis, it is nice to mention these kind of things to prevent misconceptions.

Comment: I thought that it was clear that my code was an expansion of the answer by @Luis. I just wanted to collect all the answers and the code discussed in this post at once, as it might be easier for other people with the same problem to understand it. I will specify it next time.